# how to create temp type in ElasticSearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, types, temp

I want to use it like temp table in SQL. That mean, I can create it, update and delete temp type in ElasticSearch with name each type is various. In my case with SQL, temp table can call many time and control them by name with suffix is containerNo. So in ElasticSearch, I don't know how to set name for temp type and control it. I was researched about temp index, temp type.. and I knowed plug in DeleteByQuery for delete type and delete index. But I still used it. I code with ElasticSearch 2.4 and .NET C#. Please help me !

Comment: There's no notion of temporary index in ES, but any index you create can be treated as a temporary one. An index has the meaning you give it. So very simply: create index, do some stuff on it, delete it, done.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will try it